# Node js express app using fast-csv stream parser can't redirect on "data-invalid"

Tags: node.js, csv, express, redirect, http-headers

Im creating a tool for uploading csv files to fill a database and then display data in different forms from the database.

The error im getting:
(2 first rows are console logs from .on("data-invalid"))

(this happens when im uploading a falsy file that has 6 columns when 7 is the expected.)

```
wrong format this was columns:6
wrong format this was columns:6
_http_outgoing.js:504
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:504:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:511:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/arvid.larsson/Documents/lead-data-bank/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:725:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (/Users/arvid.larsson/Documents/lead-data-bank/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:842:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (/Users/arvid.larsson/Documents/lead-data-bank/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:880:18)
    at ParserStream.<anonymous> (/Users/arvid.larsson/Documents/lead-data-bank/app.js:82:16)
    at emitThree (events.js:135:13)
    at ParserStream.emit (events.js:216:7)
    at spreadArgs (/Users/arvid.larsson/Documents/lead-data-bank/node_modules/fast-csv/lib/extended.js:49:25)
    at ParserStream.emit (/Users/arvid.larsson/Documents/lead-data-bank/node_modules/fast-csv/lib/parser/parser_stream.js:325:13)
```

My code:

```
app.post('/upload', singleCsv, function(request, response){

  var filepath = request.file.path;
  var options = {
    objectMode: true,
    headers: true,
    ignoreEmpty: true,
    trim: true
  };

  var stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);

  var parser = csv.fromStream(stream, options)
    .validate(function(data, next){
      // validate the csv
      return Object.keys(data).length == Object.keys(dbv).length - 1
    })
    .on("data-invalid", function(data){
      // This row is sent 2 times (probabaly the problem)
      console.log('wrong format this was columns:' + Object.keys(data).length.toString());
      response.redirect('/fileUpload?q=error');
    })
    .on("data", function(data) {
      setImmediate(() => {
        dbUpload.data2db(data, function(err) {
          if(err){
            console.log(err)
          }
        });
      });
    })
    .on("end", function(){
      response.redirect('/q=upload');
    });
});
```

Here's the route I'm trying to redirect to.

```
app.get('/fileUpload', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/views/fileUpload.html'))
});
```

Maybe I can end the parser on data-invalid and then redirect? But i dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looks like that you must stop reading/parsing on error.

```
var err;
var parser = csv.fromStream(stream, options)
    .validate(function(data, next) { ... })
    .on("data-invalid", function(data) {
        err = new Error ('wrong format this was columns:' + Object.keys(data).length);  
        parser.end(); // <<< stop parser
    })
    .on("data", function(data) { ... });
    .on("end", function(){
        if (err)
            console.error(err.message);
        response.redirect((err) ? '/fileUpload?q=error' : '/q=upload');
    });
```

Comment: The problem remained with your solution, I solved it by using my own check function and raised the error if it returned false and ended the parser. Else it kept on like normal.